# cannot find handleselect react-date-range

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am working on  a project on React js using react-date-range . It is causing some problems , if anyone can provide help .

I have installed first react-date-range using these commands :
npm install react-date-range
&
npm install --save react-date-range

but when I have imported it for implementation it is showing a red line under it :
import {DateRangePicker} from '**react-date-range**'

Also handleSelect function is showing error ,
this is the first part of code without import statements :

```
const PageHeader: React.FC = () => {
    const selectionRange = {
        startDate: new Date(),
        endDate: new Date(),
        key: 'selection',
    }
    handleSelect(ranges){
        console.log(ranges);

    }
```

This part is showing error :

*handleSelect(ranges){
console.log(ranges);

}*

This is the second part of the code just under it :

```
return (
    <Row>
      <Col span={24}>
        <div className="page-title">
            <b>Charts</b>
        </div>
          <DateRangePicker
              ranges={[selectionRange]}
              onChange={this.handleSelect}
          />
      </Col>
```

This part is showing error :

```
          *onChange={this.handleSelect}*
```

Please note that the extension of the file is tsx

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have a typo:

```
function handleSelect(ranges){ // add the function keyword
     console.log(ranges);
}
```

OR:

```
const handleSelect = (ranges) => { // add the arrow function assignment 
     console.log(ranges);
}
```

Also, as I see you are not in a class component, hence you don't need the **this** keyword.

```
onChange={handleSelect} // right here
```

Comment: It is showing me parameter range implicitly has any type , thanks for your answer

Comment: In the console it is showing correct range values but there is many console errors ; also there is an output of the calendar

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using function component so we need to declare `handleSelect` and we don't use `this` keyword.

```
const handleSelect = (ranges: Array<Date>) => {
    console.log(ranges);
}

onChange={handleSelect}
```

Comment: Mate what's that syntax. To declare function variable you need to provide arrow syntax. Or add function keyword in front of the name to use a regular function declaration

Comment: Thanks but it still showing errors , I write it before return ?

Comment: It is showing me prameter ranges implicitly has an any type

Comment: After updating type data , it is not showing anymore error, the only error still in import statement even it outputing daterange picker , under react-date-range it is showing error